# node.js server won't stop running

Tags: node.js, express, vite

I have done pretty much everything I can think of to troubleshoot this issue I'm having..
For whatever reason I cannot get the port to stop running even after killing the port

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that your code doesn't try to start two servers on the same port?

Comment: I've killed everything running on port 5000. But in the meantime I switched everything to port 8000 and it's working again